# Is a corrupted screen the result of bad graphic drivers?

Tags: driver, nvidia, blender, photoshop, corruption

Using Blender 2.82a I encountered this screen glitch:

[image: Blender Corruption Error]

But I had a similar issue with Photoshop 2020 where the GUI had similar glitches. And lastly, Minecraft with the SevTech Ages modpack. This doesn't happen with other software (Firefox, Excel, VSC, Sublime Text, WSL). This makes me think it's should be a graphic drivers issue. I uninstalled the NVIDIA drivers and left Windows reinstall them. I didn't encounter the issue again yet. Can anyone confirm this is a bad drivers issue? I couldn't find much information online (or didn't know what to search for).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot assuredly say that this is a driver problem, but the same happened with me with my old PC. My old PC was very low-end. It was very slow in Blender, but got the work done. To make my PC faster, I saw a youtube tutorial which showed that going to System > advanced system options > graphics and switching off all 'fancy' features will make your PC faster. Doing this resulted in the same glitches in blender and inkscape, but got fixed by switching those options bak to what they were before.